# Bash: Where did I go wrong with this?

Tags: bash, if-statement, svg, sed

I am having trouble getting this script to work, I am attempting to colour a set of `.svg` files in a directory a certain colour depending on a suffix in the filename. On execution, the script produces no errors but the files are unchanged, colour-wise.

**Edit:** The files are for a ASCII character-based tileset, and have filenames that are structured like this: "`a^[bb].svg`", The carat is optional and denotes that the character in the tile is a capital letter, while the string between the square brackets denotes the colour of character in the tile.

Here is the **updated** script that I'm trying to get working:

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in $(find *) do
if [[ $a = *bm* ]]
then
sed -i -e "s/fill:#FFFFFF/fill:#FF55FF/i" -e "s/font-size:75px/font-size:75px;fill:#FF55FF/" $a
elif [[ $a = *bb* ]] then
sed -i -e "s/fill:#FFFFFF/fill:#5555FF/i" -e "s/font-size:75px/font-size:75px;fill:#5555FF/" $a
elif [[ $a = *bc* ]] then
sed -i -e "s/fill:#FFFFFF/fill:#55FFFF/i" -e "s/font-size:75px/font-size:75px;fill:55FFFF/" $a
elif [[ $a = *br* ]] then
sed -i -e "s/fill:#FFFFFF/fill:#AA5500/i" -e "s/font-size:75px/font-size:75px;fill:#AA5500/" $a
elif [[ $a = *b* ]] then
sed -i -e "s/fill:#FFFFFF/fill:#0000AA/i" -e "s/font-size:75px/font-size:75px;fill:#0000AA/" $a
elif [[ $a = *c* ]] then
sed -i -e "s/fill:#FFFFFF/fill:#00AAAA/i" -e "s/font-size:75px/font-size:75px;fill:#00AAAA/" $a
elif [[ $a = *dgr* ]] then
sed -i -e "s/fill:#FFFFFF/fill:#555555/i" -e "s/font-size:75px/font-size:75px;fill:#555555/" $a
elif [[ $a = *g* ]] then
sed -i -e "s/fill:#FFFFFF/fill:#00AA00/i" -e "s/font-size:75px/font-size:75px;fill:#00AA00/" $a
elif [[ $a = *lgr* ]] then
sed -i -e "s/fill:#FFFFFF/fill:#AAAAAA/i" -e "s/font-size:75px/font-size:75px;fill:#AAAAAA/" $a
elif [[ $a = *m* ]] then
sed -i -e "s/fill:#FFFFFF/fill:#AA00AA/i" -e "s/font-size:75px/font-size:75px;fill:#AA00AA/" $a
elif [[ $a = *o* ]] then
sed -i -e "s/fill:#FFFFFF/fill:#FF5555/i" -e "s/font-size:75px/font-size:75px;fill:#FF5555/" $a
elif [[ $a = *r* ]] then
sed -i -e "s/fill:#FFFFFF/fill:#AA0000/i" -e "s/font-size:75px/font-size:75px;fill:#AA0000/" $a
elif [[ $a = *u* ]] then
sed -i -e "s/fill:#FFFFFF/fill:#FFFF55/i" -e "s/font-size:75px/font-size:75px;fill:#FFFF55/" $a
fi
done
sed -i -e "s/monospace/courier/gi" *
```

Comment: Don't use `==` with `[`. It's not guaranteed to work with all implementations of `[`, and when it does, you probably have the superior `[[` available.

Comment: Do you mean that your filenames have literal brackets in the filenames, as in `a[b].svg`? Would you mind to post a small set of couples of filename and expected substitution?

Comment: @gboffi here's the ``ls`` of the ``v`` directory: ``v.svg     v[bb].svg  v[bm].svg  v[c].svg    v[g].svg    v[m].svg  v[r].svg  v^.svg     v^[bb].svg  v^[bm].svg  v^[c].svg    v^[g].svg    v^[m].svg  v^[r].svg
v[b].svg  v[bc].svg  v[br].svg  v[dgr].svg  v[lgr].svg  v[o].svg  v[y].svg  v^[b].svg  v^[bc].svg  v^[br].svg  v^[dgr].svg  v^[lgr].svg  v^[o].svg  v^[y].svg``

Answer (score 2):

Replace all two letter patterns like

```
if [ $a == "*[bm]*" ]; then
```

with

```
if [[ $a = *bm* ]]; then
```

and single letter patterns

```
if [ $a == "*[m]*" ]; then
```

with

```
if [[ $a = *m* ]]; then
```

In the above glob pattern was used. In glob `*` matches any number of characters and `[bm]` matches any one from the list whether it may be `b` or `m` but not the substring `bm`.

Comment: It's not necessary to use `=~` here - you could just use `[[ $a = *[bm]* ]]`

Comment: I think he also wants `*bm*` (no brackets), since `*[bm]*` would alway match any file that matches the pattern `*[m]*` that he tests for later.

Comment: @chepner Think you're correct, failed to see the last m.

Comment: ```../dev/colour.sh: line 17: syntax error in conditional expression
../dev/colour.sh: line 17: syntax error near `]'
../dev/colour.sh: line 17: `elif [[ $a = *b* ]'
```

Comment: sorry, forget to add `]` at the end. Try now.. check my update.

Comment: @avinash-raj ```../dev/colour.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `if'
../dev/colour.sh: line 4: `if [[ $a = *bm* ]]```